# import jsonp in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, jsonp

How can I import a jsonp file in a MySQL table using PHP in the most easiest way without configuring the table?

Better if there is any existing system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just get the json string and do `serialize(json_decode($jsonstring))` and store that in a single column of your database to preserve the entire array or object and its structure then to use it from a query you'd just do `unserialize()` to convert it back to its original state.